# do crawlers decode html entities?

Tags: html, seo, entities, web-crawler

i was wondering if the crawlers and robots can decode html entities for example in my html i have something like:

```
salari&eacute;s
```

do they read it like that? or something like:

```
salariés
```

which option is better for SEO?

Comment: If optimizing your website for search engines is your goal, you're worrying about the wrong things.

Comment: better question for webmasters.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say you can safely assume that HTML entities are properly decoded. They are valid HTML, and a crawler not decoding them would end up with tons of broken content.

Comment: More than likely, any less-than-modern crawlers would just ignore things that they don't understand anyway.  Otherwise they'd never get anything done.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the crawlers will decode your entities, as they need pure text to compute the data and extract information.

If you want to help them, use an appropriate encoding (as utf8), a good charset meta, and avoid html entities.